# eBay Digital Signature for Restful APIs / sign Signature-Base with given Private Key in C#

Tags: c#, .net, digital-signature, bouncycastle, ebay-api

I struggled and messed around for about two days to create the digital signature for the specific API calls mentioned at:
https://developer.ebay.com/develop/guides/digital-signatures-for-apis

As the documentation - especially for C# - is pretty poor, particularly for this critical change in calling the Restful APIs, I want to share my finally working solution.

Overall, my question was to create all the headers and the signed signature base.

---

Already using the 'OAuth scope' with access token created with the client credentials grant flow, creating the signing keys by the 'Key Management API' was not a big deal.

My first problem was Error 215114 saying 'The create time of signature parameters is not in right range', as I thought I need to use the creation time of the created signing keys. But you need to use the time of the call.

I first created the signing keys with RSA-SHA256 cipher, but as I struggled to sign the signature base and eBay recommends Ed25519 cipher, I gave Ed25519 a try and created new keys with it.

Nevertheless I struggled with signing the signature base for the 'Signature'-header, received 215002 error ('Internal errors as fetching master key') in the meantime, and after all ended with error  215120 resp. 215122 'Signature validation failed'.

I'm using .NET 6 and RestSharp for the actual API call, tried the 'RSA Class' from System.Security.Cryptography, but now use BouncyCastle for signing in my working solution.

Comment: My question these days was to make a successful call ;-). I explained my problems in my 'question'. I wrote the answer while you commented.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is my working solution with successful response, using RestSharp and BouncyCastle, with given eBay access token and Ed25519-signing keys.

The keys are not in PEM format, like so:
JWE:
eyJ6aXAiOiJERUYiLCJraWQiOiJiNmI4ZW[...]
Private Key:
MC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEIDIpPLbihtModG[...]
Public Key:
MCowBQYDK2VwAyEA0CjbDt2NDS7LKbQS6i[...]

I think I solved my problem with successfully signing the base by noting it with "-----BEGIN ... KEY-----" and "-----END ... KEY-----" and create the key parameters with PemReader.

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using RestSharp;

// EXTERNAL METHOD TO RETRIEVE A VALID ACCESS TOKEN
EbayAccessToken ebayAccessToken = EbayAccessToken.Instance;
if (await ebayAccessToken.GetValidToken(CommonInterfaces.Resources.CommonDataPath) == null)
{
    ebayAccessToken = await WebViewCommonCalls.RenewEbayApiToken(ebayAccessToken);
}

// EXTERNAL METHOD TO RETRIEVE THE SIGNING KEYS
SigningKeyResponse keyResponse = await KeyManagement.Instance(CommonInterfaces.Resources.CommonDataPath).GetSigningKeys(ebayAccessToken.AccessToken.Token);

long timeStamp = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
string url = "https://apiz.ebay.com";
string endpoint = "/sell/finances/v1/seller_funds_summary"; // EXAMPLE CALL FOR TESTING

// BEGAN TO IMPLEMENT THE Content-Digest FOR THE PAYLOAD IN POST CALLS
//string sha256Hash = ComputeSha256Hash(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload));

string signatureParams = "(\"x-ebay-signature-key\" \"@method\" \"@path\" \"@authority\");created=" + timeStamp;

string signatureBase = 
    $"\"x-ebay-signature-key\": {keyResponse.Jwe}\n" +
    $"\"@method\": GET\n" +
    $"\"@path\": {endpoint}\n" +
    $"\"@authority\": apiz.ebay.com\n" +
    $"\"@signature-params\": {signatureParams}";
byte[] signatureBaseBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signatureBase);
string signatureBase64 = string.Empty;

// FINALLY THIS WAS THE ONLY METHOD WHICH WORKED FOR ME, BY NOTING THE KEYS IN PEM FORMAT AND LOAD IT WITH PEM READER
string privKeyString = $"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n{keyResponse.PrivateKey}\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
string pubKeyString = $"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n{keyResponse.PublicKey}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

// Sign
PemReader pemReader = new(new StringReader(privKeyString));
AsymmetricKeyParameter pemPrivKey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pemReader.ReadObject();
ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("Ed25519");
signer.Init(true, pemPrivKey);
signer.BlockUpdate(signatureBaseBytes , 0, signatureBaseBytes.Length);
byte[] signedSignatureBytes = signer.GenerateSignature();
signatureBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(signedSignatureBytes);

// Verify
PemReader pemPubReader = new(new StringReader(pubKeyString));
AsymmetricKeyParameter pemPubKey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pemPubReader.ReadObject();
ISigner verifier = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("Ed25519");
verifier.Init(false, pemPubKey);
verifier.BlockUpdate(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signatureBase), 0, signatureBase.Length);
bool verified = verifier.VerifySignature(signedSignatureBytes);

//if (!verified) return;

RestClient client = new(url)
{
    Authenticator = new RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth2.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(ebayAccessToken.AccessToken.Token, "Bearer"),
};

RestRequest request = new(endpoint, method: Method.Get);
Dictionary<string, string> headers = new()
{
    { "Content-Type", "application/json" },
    { "X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID", "EBAY-DE" },
    { "x-ebay-signature-key", keyResponse.Jwe },
    { "x-ebay-enforce-signature", "true" },
    { "Signature", $"sig1=:{signatureBase64}:" },
    { "Signature-Input", "sig1=" + signatureParams },
};
request.AddHeaders(headers);

RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    // CUSTOM CLASS 'RestfulErrorResponse' FOR DESERIALIZING RESPONSE ERRORS
    RestfulErrorResponse errors = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RestfulErrorResponse>(response.Content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the decoding of the keys from the response, it appears that you could decode the private key like this:

```
Org.BouncyCastle.Security.PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(keyResponse.PrivateKey))
```

Similarly the public key:

```
Org.BouncyCastle.Security.PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(keyResponse.PublicKey))
```

Comment: Going via PemReader is a bit awkward and note that it may not work so easily for other key algorithms once the data becomes long enough that it should be wrapped to multiple lines.